# How to set each element of array from new line

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to set each element of array entered in input from new line, i trued to do it likes this join("\n") - didn't work for me. How can i do it properly

Here is my code

```
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var list = document.querySelector('#list');
var arr = [];

btn.addEventListener('click', function(str) {
  var valInp = inp.value;
  arr.push(valInp);
  inp.value = "";
  list.innerHTML = arr.join(" "); 

});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e9k88y3/)

Comment: use </br>, .join("</br>") check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5e9k88y3/1/

Comment: Replace "\n" with "<br> like `list.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>");` This will work as you expected.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/5e9k88y3/2/ Use `<br>` instead of `' '`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `<br />` instead of `\n`

```
list.innerHTML = arr.join('<br />');
```

`\n` is a [new line character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

`<br />` is an [HTML element for a line break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).